# How does one go from a Unicode character to its description?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding

I came across this cute little symbol today:

> 

I couldn't figure out what it was, so I searched for reverse lookup services and character maps that might be able to reveal a name to no avail. I know, however, that Windows' character map program knows the names of symbols:

[image]

How does Windows accomplish this? How might I, but a lowly programmer, divine this same knowledge? What encoding system does Unicode use to tie a symbol to its description?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information comes from the [Unicode Character Database](http://unicode.org/ucd/).

Specifically, the code points and their names (and other info like the category of a code point) are defined in [UnicodeData.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt).

A lot of programming languages have this information in the standard library, eg. the `unicodedata` module of Python.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to know the glyph name, head on over to [CodePoints](https://codepoints.net/) (or [Graphemica](http://graphemica.com/) or probably any one of a dozen other sites) and do a search on it. I'm not sure which lookup services you used "to no avail" but those two have no issues in locating it.

Doing so with  will lead you to [codepoint U+1F52e](https://codepoints.net/U+1F52E), which will give you the descriptive name "CRYSTAL BALL", along with all sorts of other useful information about it.