# where can I find a data representation of the unicode 9.0 standard?

Tags: unicode

I'm asking again because this question got put on hold:

[is there a file/data representation of the unicode 9.0 standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668728/is-there-a-file-data-representation-of-the-unicode-9-0-standard)

there is a website http://unicode.org/ that lists the standard

and there is a page here - http://www.unicode.org/charts/ that has pdfs of all the scripts. For example, 1E900 to 1E95F is reserved for Adlam.

I'm hoping there is some sort of `unicode.metadata` file that can be read in and parsed so that the following queries can be made:

- what is the code range for Osmanya?
- how many characters are there for Brahmi?

Comment: There is one, see [How does one go from a Unicode character to its description?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360359/how-does-one-go-from-a-unicode-character-to-its-description). Also I think JAVA has a built-in API to query that information.

Comment: The latest data files are always in http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/ .

Comment: nice! that's what I needed.

Comment: Why the `clojure` tag?

Comment: oh... cos I find the clojure community a bit more friendly when it comes to SO... but someone removed the tag anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode is a large standard. The JDK (if it is the Java platform you’re interested in) does not provide APIs that cover ‘all of Unicode’.

I believe the most popular library out there is [**ICU**](http://site.icu-project.org/).

If however the queries you mentioned are all that you’re interested in, then perhaps the `java.lang.Character` API is all you need.

- [`java.lang.Character.UnicodeBlock.OSMANYA`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html#OSMANYA) (though I see no method to obtain the codepoint range)
- [`java.lang.Character.UnicodeBlock.BRAHMI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html#BRAHMI)

You can for example query whether a codepoint is within the range for Osmanya, by testing the value of `(Character$UnicodeBlock/of 1234)` for equivalence with `Character$UnicodeBlock/OSMANYA`.